# The best approach to discovering the output of code examples

Tags: java

How should one go about looking through code to discover its true output? What are the most common pitfalls people fall into? Is there any tips/tricks you can provide to someone new to java programming? Here is an example of code which I want to find the output of. Rather than plugging into eclipse. What might be an effective approach to finding its output on a sheet of paper.

Thank you

```
double valueOne = 20.0, valueTwo = 30.0; 

if ((valueOne > valueTwo) || (valueOne >= 0.0)) { 
valueOne -= 1.0; 
System.out.println("valueOne: " + valueOne); 
} else { 
valueTwo += 2.0; 
System.out.println("valueTwo: " + valueTwo); 
} 

String messageOne = "Hello"; 
if (messageOne.equals("HELLO")) { 
System.out.println("Hello processed"); 
} else { 
System.out.println("Hello ignored"); 
} 

String messageTwo = new String("Hello"); 
if (messageOne.equals(messageTwo)){ 
System.out.println("Caseone"); 
}else { 
System.out.println("CaseTwo"); 
} 
if (messageOne == messageTwo) { 
System.out.println("CaseThree"); 
} else { 
System.out.println("CaseFour"); 
}
```

Comment: How should I set it up?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Pens-Refills-Writing-Correction-Supplies/b?ie=UTF8&node=1069820 and http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=paper&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apaper

Comment: I just want a general process here to analyzing code.

Comment: Code executes left to right. Do the same thing on paper.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a homework question...

Comment: To commenters: no need for the snark; at one time, we were all beginners learning to program. To the questioner: you can try copy-pasting each line into a web-based [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for Java such as: http://www.javarepl.com/console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, **pen and paper** is the way to go if you do not want to execute your code.

Otherwise, you can **debug** using eclipse to be able to **see step by step how your program behaves**.
You can easily find some debugging tutorial on eclipse, such as:
http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/

Answer (score 0):

Just pretend you're compiling the code in your head. You can use pen and paper to help, write down after every instruction so you can watch the progress. Search for programming logic, take some online course, it helps you with that and other beginner questions ;)